# return floats instead of ndarray in pandas - python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'c1':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'c2':['a','b','a','b','a','a','b','b'],'c3':['w','w','x','x','w','x','w','x'],'c4':[90,28,31,10,21,55,49,23]})

>>> groups = df.groupby(['c1','c3'])

>>> groups.apply(lambda x: x[x['c2']=='b'].c4.values / x[x['c2']=='a'].c4.values)

c1   c2   
1    w    [0.31111]
     x    [0.32258]
2    w    [2.33333]
     x    [0.41818]
```

Is there a way to make the operation above return float values instead of an ndarray?

```
c1   c2   
1    w    0.31111
     x    0.32258
2    w    2.33333
     x    0.41818
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can convert output to `Series`:

```
df = groups.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[x['c2']=='b'].c4 / x[x['c2']=='a'].c4.values))
           .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
print (df)
c1  c3
1   w     0.311111
    x     0.322581
2   w     2.333333
    x     0.418182
Name: c4, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Glad can help you!